# Is there a file diff tool that allows for exceptions?

Tags: java, beyondcompare3, file-diffs

We currently use Beyond Compare 3.0 and I am quite pleased with it. However, it would be great if I could easily specify an exclusion for a specific one-time case. This is needed when I am doing a code review of some refactoring. For instance:

Old code

```
doSomething(ConstantsInterface.FOOBAR);
```

New code:

```
doSomething(BetterEnumeration.FOOBAR);
```

In this case, I have hundreds of changes that I am reviewing that are essentially all the same exact change and I just want to see the exceptions. It would be great if I could easily specify an exception that indicates these two cases are equal. I know of a way to do it in the grammar, but it is tedious and cumbersome in the case where there are ten or so exceptions.

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare's Pro edition supports ignoring renamed identifiers.  It's covered in the help [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/help/index.html?text_compare_replacements.html), and there's a video demonstration of it [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/videos/WN3Replacements.html).  It's not limited to just identifiers either;  it can handle things like `i=i+1` => `i++`.  If you have a recent version installed you can just right click on the difference and select "Replacement..." to get started.

Answer (score 1):

1) Write one line regex to switch them all back.

2) Diff, see any exceptions

3) Run reverse of regex in step 1

Done in 5 minutes